# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.FormFields.Item does not exist in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, office-interop

I am upgrading a Windows application that was designed in Visual Studio 2005 and .Net 2 to Visual Studio 2010. One function of the application allows the end-user to open an existing MS Word document which is pre-populated with data from the active Window (i.e. customer account #, name, etc). The existing code that sets the field value is as follows:

```
public void SetField(string fieldName, string value)
{
    object fName = fieldName;
    try
    {
        document.FormFields.Item(ref fName).Result = value;
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message != "The requested member of the collection does not exist.")
        throw;
    }
}
```

The "Item" method no longer exists. Is there a replacement?

Comment: It's [still in the documentation for 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.formfields.item.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a project reference to that DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.formfields.item.aspx), it looks like it's just become an index - so maybe

```
document.FormFields[fName].Result = value;
```

(originally I had `FormFields[ref fName]` - as commented below the `ref` was wrong.)

Comment: Heh - I left the `ref` out to start with then came back and edited it in. Should have stuck with my first instinct after all.